# Polar Coordinate Surface Integral

Tags: calculus, geometry

Been staring at this question for hours, to no avail..

Let $S$ be the paraboloid parametrised in polar coordinates as

$$t(r,x)=(r\cos \phi,r \sin \phi,r^2), \qquad r\geq 0, \quad 0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi.$$

Evaluate the double integral of $\iint \frac{1}{(1+4z)^2} \mathrm{d}S$

Comment: I just answered this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329900/polar-surface-integral

Answer (score 2):

The representation $t$ maps an infinitesimal annulus of radius $r$ and width $dr$ onto an infinitesimal lampshade of radius $r$ and width $${dr\over\cos\theta(r)}\ ,$$
where $$\tan\theta(r)={\partial z\over \partial r}=2r\ ,\quad{\rm i.e.},\quad \cos\theta={1\over\sqrt{1+4r^2}}\ .$$
It follows that
$$dS=2\pi r\ \sqrt{1+4r^2}\ dr\ ,$$
and our integral ($=:Q)$ becomes
$$Q=\int_0^\infty{2\pi r \sqrt{1+4r^2}\over (1+4r^2)^2}\ \ dr={\pi \over2}\int_0^\infty{4r\over (1+4r^2)^{3/2}}\ dr=\ldots={\pi\over2}\ .$$